# Custom image button with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, css, cordova, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-button

I'm trying to build an interface for my first mobile app and the app has to work on both Android and Windows Phone, so I'm using PhoneGap + jQuery Mobile.

To design the UI i'm working with [Appery](http://appery.io).

What I need to do is to have something like a full screen toggle button with a custom image on it.

I've got 3 copies of the image, one for each status.

Let's say that I have:

- Image on.png for the on status
- Image off.png for the off status
- Image pressed.png to be shown until the user releases the button

I'm using this code to show the first image on the button:

```
$("[name='toggleOnOff']").text("").append("<img height=\"300\" src=\"off.png\" width=\"280\"/>").button();
```

but I don't know how to do the different states to customize my button.

I've tried with *ThemeRoller* but it just allows me to change the button's color and that's not what I need.

EDIT:
This is the HTML for the button:

```
<a data-role="button" name="toggleOnOff" dsid="toggleOnOff" class='  mobilebutton2'
    id='j_5' data-corners="true" data-mini="false" data-theme="a" tabIndex="2">
    Button
</a>
```

Comment: Show us button html you are trying to change.

Comment: Added the code for the button.

Comment: You could just use JS variables or CSS classes to define states. Either set a value of say.. the "state" variable to off/on/pressed or use addClass/removeClass to add/remove the class of .on/.off/.pressed

You can then either set the background image in CSS or use .append like you are in combination with a collection of  `if` statements to determine which image to append/remove

Comment: Should button also have dimensions 280px*300px?

Comment: Yes, button and image should have the sime size but I'm open to any alternative solution. @Calvin are you saying something like making 3 css classes, one for each button status, and than change the button's class everytime I tap on the button? Appery doesn't give me a "released" event so I have just "click", "tap" and "taphold". Can you provide a working sample of what you mean?

Comment: @StepTNT here's a really basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/j58Jw/4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/GFnyg/

**HTML :**

```
<a data-role="button" class="toggleOnButton" id='toggleButton' data-corners="true" data-mini="false" data-theme="a" tabIndex="2"></a>
```

**CSS :**

```
.toggleOnButton {
    width: 280px !important;    
    height: 300px !important;   
    background: transparent url('http://www.projectpuppylove.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/cropped-puppy_vet.jpg') no-repeat center center !important; 
}

.toggleOffButton {
    background: transparent url('http://www.strawberryreef.com/images/Accessories/G4animals/cat2_pink.jpg') no-repeat center center !important;   
}

.toggleOnButton:active {
    background: transparent url('http://talliscountry.co.uk/uploads/Small%20Pets.jpg') no-repeat center center !important; 
}
```

**Javascript :**

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
    $("#toggleButton").on("click", function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("toggleOffButton");
    });    
});
```

Comment: It works! +1 for the images :D Just a little side question: what if I want this images' size to be relative to screen's resolution? I'm trying with `width: 90% !important; height: 70% !important;` with no success!

Comment: Do you want button to be relative to screen resolution or images because images are just button background?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was talking about the buttons! Your css is perfect for a 320x480 screen but it's not that good on a 400x800 one (at least according to Appery's preview!)

Comment: I have updated my jsFiddle. Take a look. I have added another css line, it will take a care that picture is always stretched with an image. So you can use any button dimensions and picture will follow it. Now your other question regarding % measurements. They could cause some problems, specially in case of my jsFiddle example. If you you use % size it will take a look at parent container and that is our data-role="content" container. But data-role="content" div container will not cover full page height unless you put some content into it. Without content its height is around 50px.

Comment: So if your picture has height 90% its final height will be 90% of 50px.